# What can I do to polish and refine my new homebrew class?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, class

I just finished writing a rough draft of a new homebrew class for the Forgotten Realms setting. Ultimately it's for a specific player's personal needs and interests, but I tried to design it with multiple avenues so that it could be replayable and potentially useful to others.

I have a couple of friends reviewing this draft right now, but you can only get so far when you're all so close to the work.

How can I get the feedback I need to further polish and refine this class so that's it would be good enough to share outside our group?

Comment: This is still asking for recommendations (“An online community […] but I don't know which ones will have the qualities I'm looking for.”), just obliquely. Unfortunately, this site isn't a general-purpose RPG community and some things are off topic. Recommendations are among those things. I'm going to do an edit to fully expunge the request for recommendations, but I'm not going to reopen it immediately — I'll want confirmation first of whether the end result is something you're actually interested in. (If not, we recommend using an actual general-purpose forum; links in the banner on the Q.)

Comment: How does that look? Is this revised question something still relevant to your situation?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie [done](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7612/i-really-dont-think-this-question-on-how-to-get-feedback-on-homebrew-material-w)